# Android - Unable to start Camera from Floating View / Service - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-camera, android-databinding

I'm attempting to create a Floating View (somewhat like Facebook Messenger's floating user image)

***Example:***
https://www.cnet.com/a/img/YcbyFcLt1YoAYIvkKOLIvUqDZbU=/1200x630/2013/04/12/5b94f150-f0e0-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/Facebook_Messenger_ChatHeads.jpg

**Problem:**

When I attempt to do so using the following code - the Camera preview is never started/populated/displayed, and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions/tips/ideas are appreciated.

**Source Snippet:**

```
class FloatingViewService : Service() {

    private val context: Context? = null
    private val mView: View? = null
    private var mParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams? = null
    private var mWindowManager: WindowManager? = null

    private lateinit var binding: OverlayLayoutBinding
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private var mFloatingView: View? = null
    private var params: WindowManager.LayoutParams? = null
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) startMyOwnForeground() else startForeground(
            1,
            Notification()
        )
        //Inflate the floating view layout we created
        mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null)
        val LAYOUT_FLAG: Int
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
        
        startCamera()

        mWindowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager?
        mWindowManager!!.addView(mFloatingView, params)

        startCamera()

    }

    private fun startCamera() {

        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider
            .getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({

            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also { mPreview ->
                    mPreview.setSurfaceProvider(
                        binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider
                    )
                }
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()

            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    (context as LifecycleOwner),
                    cameraSelector,
                    preview, imageCapture
                )

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Camera Failed to Start")
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

}
```

**Full Source:**

https://pastebin.com/3wG1QP98

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ClgD3HLZaQ25toalygAZphuR7XUA3QRG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Since you are handling exception, have you checked logcat for any message like "Camera Failed to Start" ? Also try to print stack trace and see if anything is going wrong.

Comment: Yes - I have - the error is not logged and the exception is never hit if I set a breakpoint

Comment: @GokulNathKP - I just added the full source - perhaps that may provide more insight